# admin.messaging is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Problem solved!
Because of the old version.

---

I try my best already but cannot find out any solution on stackoverflow/google/firebase.

I build-up node.js on linux server, and cannot use the function of Cloud Messaging in firebase.
I can connect to the database on firebase successfully.
But I cannot use the Cloud Messaging service.

I am very new on coding, so please tell me if I have any basic error.

some of my code on node.js:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount_2 = require("/home/____________.json");
var app_V2 = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount_2),
  databaseURL: "https://_______.firebaseio.com"
}, "myapp");

var payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "This is Title",
          body: "This is Msg body"
        }
      };

var topic = "some_topic";

admin.messaging().sendToTopic(topic, payload)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        });
```

I tried many time but still have the same error.

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: admin.messaging is not a function

TypeError: admin.messaging is not a function
```

I tried using the same code on 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic
but still having the same error.

Comment: Can you run `npm version firebase` and tell what it reports back?

Comment: I havn't build a "package.json", i cannot check it with _"npm version firebase"_

but my version should be _firebase-admin@4.1.1_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you have an older version installed. I was able to run the current version [via RunKit](https://runkit.com/npm/firebase-admin) just fine (minus proper credentials of course). Double check the installed version by running `npm ls firebase-admin` from the root directory of your project (where you ran `npm install firebase-admin` from).

Comment: I reinstall everything and it can run now.
Thanks so much!